# Tried a simple Python 3.4.3 program on Mac using Curses and got this error error: endwin() returned ERR

Tags: python, user-input, curses

I'm trying to get user input without having to hit return, I looked towards the curses library. But every time I try to run the program:

```
import curses
stdscr = curses.initscr()
c = stdscr.getch()
print ('you entered', chr(c))
curses.endwin()
```

all I get is this in return:

```
error                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2bb957279c64> in <module>()
3 c = stdscr.getch()
4 print ('you entered', chr(c))
----> 5 curses.endwin()

error: endwin() returned ERR
```

Any idea to why I might be getting this?

Comment: That is weird. I can report that on Ubuntu this little script runs just fine. Apart from the fact that you can't see the input, as the script immediately terminates after the print statement :).